# Angular unit testing - stubbing/mocking a directive with reference in ViewChild

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, viewchild

How do you stub/mock a directive/component that is read as a `ViewChild`?

For example, using the simple directive from angular.io:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[appHighlight]'
})
export class HighlightDirective {
  constructor() { }
}
```

Let's say that I am testing `AppComponent` and reads the `HighlightDirective` using `ViewChild` as:

```
@ViewChild(HighlightDirective) theHighlightDirective: HighlightDirective
```

And the stubbed directive is:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[appHighlight]'
})
export class StubbedHighlightDirective {
  constructor() { }
}
```

Since the component is trying to read `HighlightDirective`, even if you declare `StubbedHighlightDirective` in your unit tests, `theHighlightDirective` will be `undefined`.

Example:

```
it('HighlightDirective is defined', () => {
    // This test fails
    expect(component.theHighlightDirective).toBeDefined();
});
```

You can get around this if you ignore some things in tslint or use the `as` keyword:

```
Version 1: Just ignore some things in tslint so compiler doesn't complain
it('HighlightDirective is defined', () => {
    // Compiler will typically complain saying that
    // StubbedHighlightDirective isn't assignable to type of HighlightDirective
    component.theHighlightDirective = new StubbedHighlightDirective();

    // this passes
    expect(component.theHighlightDirective).toBeDefined();
});

Version 2: Use "as" keyword
it('HighlightDirective is defined', () => {
    // Actually compiler will still complain with warnings
    component.theHighlightDirective = new StubbedHighlightDirective() as HighlightDirective;

    // this passes
    expect(component.theHighlightDirective).toBeDefined();
});
```

Is there another way to cleanly stub out these kinds of ViewChild references?

Comment: Sorry, but i don't think that it's possible

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that you're using a class to find the child, and that class has been replaced by your stub. You can use a matching `exportAs` link in your directive ([docs](https://angular.io/api/core/Directive#exportAs), [blog post](https://netbasal.com/angular-2-take-advantage-of-the-exportas-property-81374ce24d26)) to make sure the real version and the stub have the same name.

In the original directive decorator:

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[appHighlight]',
    exportAs: 'appHighlight'
})
export class HighlightDirective {
```

In the stubbed directive:

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[appHighlight]',
    exportAs: 'appHighlight'
})
export class StubbedHighlightDirective {
```

And then in the template where the directive is used:

```
<div appHighlight #appHighlight="appHighlight">
```

With all this done you'll need to update your `@ViewChild` definition to use the string instead of the class:

```
@ViewChild('appHighlight') theHighlightDirective: HighlightDirective
```